# Finding out how many status objects are in a store

Tags: json, extjs, store

I have a store called `CreativeStore` and inside one of the fields is `Status`.  The data is sent as JSON. I created a variable that is getting the Creative store.  How would I find out what the status is and how many statuses their are.
In my Creative Model I have a field

```
 }, {
    type: 'int',
    name: 'Status'
  }, {
```

In my View Controller I have a method that checks if the store I created for the Creative Model exists (It does) and I assign it to a var called test.

```
var test = this.getCreativeStore();

  getCreativeStore: function () {
    var creativeStore = this.getStore('creativeStore');
    if (!creativeStore) {
      this.logError('creativeStore is undefined');
    }
    return creativeStore;
  }
```

How do I find out how many Statuses are in the variable test?

Comment: Not really clear on what you're asking. Are you looking to pull in a distinct set of all the status fields?

Comment: If you just need the number of records in that store `test.getCount()` should do it. If you need a distinct count, you will have to apply some logic probably using `test.each()`

Comment: `test.getCount()` or `Ext.Array.unique(test.getRange().map(function(record) {return record.get("Status")}).length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collect`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-collect):

> Collects unique values for a particular `dataIndex` from this store.

For example:

```
test.collect('status').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var statusCount = 0;

test.each(function(record) {
    // Your status value in myStatus
    if(record.get('Status') === myStatus)
        ++statusCount;
});
```